# Spring boot server startup issue elastic search

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch7.5. I have turned on the following properties

```
xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.security.authc.api_key.enabled: true
```

I have generated API keys to connect our springboot to elasticsearch.I am using

`spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch`

All my requests are from "RestHighClient" and able to trigger the requests.Only problem is during server startup, they are some errors where it is not able to connect to Elasticsearch.

```
org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: [ADMIN-PC][127.0.0.1:9300][cluster:monitor/nodes/liveness]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSecurityException: missing authentication credentials for action [cluster:monitor/nodes/liveness]
```

In pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

in application properties:

```
spring.elasticsearch.server=localhost:9200
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name=elasticsearch
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=127.0.0.1:9300
spring.data.elasticsearch.repositories.enabled=true
```

Can someone suggest me ,How I can fix it.

Comment: How do you configure the connection to Elasticsearch? It seems that Spring-Boot autoconfigures a TransportClient that connects to localhost:9300, although you use the rest client.

Comment: yes..How I can stop this

Comment: Well, how do you configure your application? Please post the relevant properties.

Comment: updated the description with pom.xml and property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove these lines from your configuration:

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name=elasticsearch
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=127.0.0.1:9300
```

These make Spring Boot to configure the transport client.